Soundproof insulation
I am trying to soundproof a room in my basement. Can I get away with using regular R20 insulation? I am using 2 layers of drywall (1/2 inch and 5/8). Or do I need to get actual soundproofing insulation? Wondering if it makes a world of a difference.

See past questions tagged "sound-proofing". (I've added that tag to your question.) This may wind up getting closed as a duplicate of those, though if you give more specifics of what you are trying to block there might be some new information

instead of fiber wool, use mineral wool, it is denser and heavier thus better sound barrier

What are your goals? Sound insulation is an important step but is not sufficient by itself for what most people would refer to as 'sound proofing'. As a recent example, we adjusted the NRR of a 80x30 wall recently by 12dB and it took 180k off the cost of construction, mostly in a reduction of detail work required. Also: What other answers here have you read through?

What level of sound proofing to you want? Simply hanging a carpet on one wall can already make a very noticeable difference. Or do you want sound recording studio levels of sound proofing?

I do intend to make it a home studio for recording vocals, but it is more so I can comfortably play music loud so my family is not disturbed two levels up. I do not have the expectations of reduce noise completely, but I do want to reduce the noise coming out of my room.
